# Error trying to scale horizontally in Azure app-service: TemplateBladeVirtualPart MICROSOFT_AZURE_MONITORING, what's the cause?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to set up horizontal scale, but when I click on the menu item, I get a screen with the following:

> TemplateBladeVirtualPart MICROSOFT_AZURE_MONITORING

Is it for some other active service added to the app-service? It's very strange, the only things I did in connection with associating with other services was adding extensions:

- Let's Encripty;
- Application Insights.

But I've already removed them for testing and I was not successful either.

[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbyAF.jpg)

**EDIT:**
I verified that the problem is being caused only in web application plans in the South Brazil region, I tried to create other plans in the same region and I got the same problem. When you create a web application plan in another region, the screen appears normally.

**EDIT2**
The problem appears to be a limitation on my account or in my region.
The fact is that in Brazil I am not able to perform horizontal scale when I am in the Basic layer of web applications.
When performing the test changing to standard, it was possible to access the desired screen.

Comment: Any chance you could include a screenshot? that would help figure out what is going on.

Comment: I added the screenshot as requested.

Comment: Let me know if the powershell workaround works for you

Comment: this issue is now fixed in production

Comment: Yes, is now available. Good job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: This issue is now fix in production.

I'm able to re-pro this for basic app service plans in Brazil south. Looks like it could be a bug in the scale UX, we'll take a look.

As a workaround you could use powershell:

```
Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName "rg-name" -Name "asp-name" -NumberofWorkers "# of workers"
```